# One-to-many relationship does not return what i expect

Tags: laravel

I have Comments integrated into my Post. When I post a Comment I try to get the User's name of a Comment by using a relationship. However, it returns a User model and not the specific User attributes itself.

I tried to dump with `dd()` the variable to see what the problem is but I can't seem to figure it out.

The relationship between `Comment` and `User.`

```php
public function author()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

public function author()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}


public function specific_post(Post $post){
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id',$post->id)->get();
    dd($comments[0]->author());

    return view('MainPages/specific_post' , compact('post' , 'comments'));
}
```

Dumping the variable returns this:

```
BelongsTo {#241 ▼
  #child: Comment {#236 ▶}
  #foreignKey: "author_id"
  #ownerKey: "id"
  #relationName: "author"
  #query: Builder {#232 ▶}
  #parent: Comment {#236 ▼
    #fillable: array:3 [▶]
    #casts: array:2 [▶]
    #hidden: array:1 [▶]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "comments"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "user_id" => 1
      "post_id" => 1
      "content" => "Hello , i really like your content!!"
      "created_at" => "2019-03-28 20:56:01"
      "updated_at" => "2019-03-28 20:56:01"
    ]
    #original: array:6 [▶]
    #changes: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
  #related: User {#235 ▼
    #fillable: array:3 [▼
      0 => "name"
      1 => "email"
      2 => "password"
    ]
    #hidden: array:2 [▼
      0 => "password"
      1 => "remember_token"
    ]
    #casts: array:1 [▼
      "email_verified_at" => "datetime"
    ]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
  }
  #withDefault: null
}
```

As you can see, there are no attributes of a particular User, and I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're dumping out the `author()` method which returns you the relationship model (which in this case does not return any data).
Dump `$comments[0]->author` instead (see that there are no brackets?) and you will have your data.

Comment: Then there is a problem somewhere else, as definining relationships in models returns data only if you access it like a property, and not as a method.